# Borrar subcadena de una cadena utilizando cierto criterio de búsqueda

Tags: c#, string, regex, str-replace

¿Existe algún método o procedimiento que permita eliminar o cambiar partes de una cadena en función de ciertos criterios?

Estoy obteniendo mediante unos métodos los directorios de varios archivos y pretendo cambiar la carpeta donde se aloja el archivo `*.txt`.

El problema es que estaba utilizando el método `.Replace()` de la clase String pero al haber una carpeta dentro de otra, ambas con el mismo nombre, me cambia el directorio completamente y no me vale esa solución.

Pongo un ejemplo más visual, el directorio es el siguiente;

Actual:

```
C:\Users\JoseCarlos\Desktop\tmp3326\tmp3326\1.txt
```

Pretendo cambiar el último nivel `tmp3326` por un `vm`, para conseguir lo siguiente:

```
C:\Users\JoseCarlos\Desktop\tmp3326\vm\1.txt
```

Pero al utilizar `.Replace()` me quedo con esta cadena:

```
C:\Users\JoseCarlos\Desktop\vm\vm\1.txt
```

En el código, la variable `archivosDirectorio` contiene un array de string con todos los ficheros:

```
for (int i = 0; i < archivosDirectorio.Length; i++)
{
    File.Move(archivosDirectorio[i], archivosDirectorio[i].Replace(nameOld, tbNuevoNombre.Text));
}
```

Cabe decir que únicamente quiero realizar la sustitución si el directorio anterior tiene el mismo nombre.

Así pues, esta ruta no se debería cambiar y permanecería invariable, puesto que `mv`, que es el último directorio, no se repite:

```
C:\Users\JoseCarlos\Desktop\mv\lolo-s001.vmdk
```

¿Lo haríais de alguna manera en concreto? Decir que los directorios y niveles de estos pueden variar, siempre conoceré el valor del último nivel, pero solo debo cambiar este y no el anterior.

Comment: Parece que no eres un usuario nuevo y sabrás que no resolvemos ideas, resolvemos problemas de código concreto. Por favor , por el código con el que recoges el directorio y haces el `replace` que no te sirve.

Comment: me he perdido... no entiendo tu problema

Comment: Dinos el contenido de `archivosDirectorio`, o mejor, ¿cómo le asignas los valores?

Comment: yo veo dos soluciones: 1.- cambiar como se asignan nombres a carpetas. 2.- if else con contador, seguramente haya un mejor método que el 2 pero te funciona

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes usar una expresión regular para cambiar el último directorio:

```
([^\\]+)\\\1(?=\\[^\\]+$)
```

Remplazar por: `$1\CAMBIADO`

Tienes una demo de la expresión regular [aquí](https://regex101.com/r/eBj3C5/2/).

Y un ejemplo del código [aquí](https://ideone.com/u46P4Q).

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        String miRuta1 = "C:\\Users\\JoseCarlos\\Desktop\\tmp3326\\tmp3326\\1.txt";
        Console.WriteLine(miRuta1);
        Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(miRuta1, "([^\\\\]+)\\\\\\1(?=\\\\[^\\\\]+$)", "$1\\CAMBIADO"));

        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------");

        String miRuta2 = "C:\\Users\\JoseCarlos\\Desktop\\mv\\lolo-s001.vmdk";
        Console.WriteLine(miRuta2);
        Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(miRuta2, "([^\\\\]+)\\\\\\1(?=\\\\[^\\\\]+$)", "$1\\CAMBIADO"));
    }
}
```

Explicación de la expresión regular:

```
([^\\]+)        # Cualquier caracter que no sea '\', repetido una o más veces.
                # ... y se guarda en el primer grupo de captura
\\              # Una '\'
\1              # Lo encontrado en el primer grupo de captura
(?=             # Debe estar precedido por:
    \\          # Una '\'
    [^\\]+      # Cualquier caracter que no sea '\', repetido una o más veces
    $           # Fin de la cadena
)
```

Comment: Ejecutando el codigo me cambia siempre la primera coincidencia, en vez de la segunda... En cambio en el simulador que propones lo realiza bien ¿?

Comment: Hola @Edulon. Podrías compartir un ejemplo con el problema? Quizás podrías usar https://www.ideone.com/ para construir un ejemplo con el problema.

Comment: Hola @Julio, este es el ejemplo https://www.ideone.com/reP81V
En teoria, ¿no deberia quedarse tal cual? Es decir, solo me interesa cambiar la segunda repeticion de subcadena, si es quela hay...

Comment: Ah, pensaba que querías remplazar *siempre* el último directorio (independientemente de si estaba duplicado o no). Ahora corrijo la respuesta

Comment: @Edulon, hecho! Mira a ver si así es lo que necesitas

Comment: si!! eso era, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción "sin usar expresiones regulares" puede ser así:

- Separar el string en un arreglo - `string[]`.
- Reemplazar la palabra deseada - en la posición del arreglo.
- Usar [string.join](https://www.dotnetperls.com/string-join) para unir de vuelta el arreglo.

Ejemplo:

```
string miRuta1 = @"C:\Users\JoseCarlos\Desktop\tmp3326\tmp3326\1.txt";
Console.WriteLine("Original: " + miRuta1);
// Original: C:\Users\JoseCarlos\Desktop\tmp3326\tmp3326\1.txt

string[] arr_palabras = miRuta1.Split('\\');
string palabra_a_reemplazar = arr_palabras[5];
Console.WriteLine("Palabra a reemplazar: " + palabra_a_reemplazar);
// Palabra a reemplazar: tmp3326

// Reemplazo:
arr_palabras[5] = "vm";
Console.WriteLine("Palabra (tmp3326) reemplazada por: " +  arr_palabras[5]);
// Palabra (tmp3326) reemplazada por: vm

string resultado = string.Join("\\", arr_palabras);
Console.WriteLine("Ruta obtenida: " + resultado);
// Ruta obtenida: C:\Users\JoseCarlos\Desktop\tmp3326\vm\1.txt
```

Comment: Está bueno, aunque para ser completo no debería tener ese `5` hardcodeado, si no ser genérico. También debería mirar si las dos últimos directorios son iguales y en tal caso hacer la susticución, ignorando el resto de casos